# Wireshark: Disable "Do you want to save..." dialog?

Tags: wireshark

In Wireshark, is there a way to hide this did-you-forget-to-save dialog that appears after clicking "Restart current capture"? I'd like to never save, and not be warned.

[image: Do you want to save?]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there is an option that controls this.

If you're using the Qt version of Wireshark, you'll find it via *Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Confirm unsaved capture files*.

If you're using the Gtk version of Wireshark, you'll find it via *Edit -> Preferences -> User Interface -> Confirm unsaved capture files*.

Comment: Version 3.6, Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> gui.ask_unsaved